# Swift 4 Refresh Control not smooth but always jump

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UIViewController, inside which there is a tableView. I added a RefreshControl. But when I pull, it always jumps for some times, which is not smooth and continuous at all.

I'm using Swift 4 and Xcode 10.1.

```
class ItemsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate, ItemCellDelegate {
    ......
    lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:
            #selector(handleRefresh(_:)),
                                 for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray

        return refreshControl
    }()
    ......
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Refresh
        self.tableView.refreshControl = self.refreshControl
    }
    ......
    @objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        loadData()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced that kind of problem. You can use this approach below:

1. Change your **handleRefresh** method like this:

   ```
   @objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
      if !tableView.isDragging {
       refresh() // refresh is another method for your reloading jobs
      }

   }
   ```
2. Add **refresh** method.

   ```
   func refresh() {
     self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
     self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
   ```
3. Lastly you need to implement **scrollViewDidEndDragging**. If you've pulled down far enough, the refreshControl will be refreshing, so call refresh. Otherwise, you either haven't pulled down far enough, you were dragging on a different part of the table, or you dragged so quickly that the refreshControl ValueChanged event has yet to fire, and it will refresh the table there.

   ```
   func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
      if refreshControl.isRefreshing == true {
       refresh()
      }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Is `loadData()` asynchronous? because if so it should have a completion handler and

```
tableView.reloadData()
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

should be done (on the main thread) from there.  Otherwise what is happening is the user pulls down and you instantly update the tableView and stop the refresh control, so thats why you have no animation.

Comment: So how do I do these after loadData() is completed?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    loadData()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now + 0.2) { // or this one with 
    //short delay
       refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes the animation become smoother, but there is still a little bit of jumping.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by doing this:

```
@objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    loadData()
}
```

Pretty simple. Now the animation is much better.
The tableView.reloadData(), which is inside of loadData(), is getting the animation **less** smooth. So I make it do after the user releases from dragging.